# Strange behavior switch-case statement in Swift

Tags: swift, switch-statement

Usually the switch-case statement works like this: if the condition exactly matches the value, then the corresponding code block is executed. But in my case, something went wrong! Why does the code for "update" work for me while the condition is "date" !? I tried to recreate the situation in the playground - everything works correctly there. What is the problem?

Why does the `update` block work when `key = "date"`? Theoretically, the `default` block should work!?

**My code:**

```
print("Dictionary = \(dictionary)")

for (key, value) in dictionary {
    switch key {
    case BaseDatabase.COLUMN_ID:
        // My code
    case WeddingDatabase.COLUMN_PREMIUM:
        // My code
    case BaseDatabase.COLUMN_UPDATE_CLEAN:
        print("type = \(BaseDatabase.COLUMN_UPDATE_CLEAN), key = \(key)")
        // My code
    default:
        // My default code
    }
}
```

**My console:**

```
dictionary = ["note": <null>, "date": 2024-08-08 00:00:00, "update": 2019-07-09 08:57:05, "id_wedding": 1]

type = update, key = date // WHY??
type = update, key = update
```

**UPDATE:**

Cut the code to the banal:

```
let key = "date"
switch key {
    case "update":
        print("key = \(key)")
    break
    default:
        print("default = \(key)")
    break
}
```

Added code in `viewDidLoad` empty viewController. The console still displays `key = date`. I see the problem ONLY in my project. I tried to add code in a new project and in playgroud - everything works fine (`default = date` is output to the console). How can this be? I tried different Simulators (and iOS versions) - the problem is still there. I also tried to clean the project - the problem persists. Maybe somewhere in the project the work of switch statement is redefined - is this possible?

Comment: A compiling self-contained example would be helpful.

Comment: @martin-r The problem is that in the standalone example, I do not observe such a problem. Everything works correctly.

Comment: How you defined `BaseDatabase.COLUMN_ID`, `WeddingDatabase.COLUMN_PREMIUM` and `BaseDatabase.COLUMN_UPDATE_CLEAN` ?

Comment: @TheTiger In the following way: `static let COLUMN_ID = "_id"`, `static let COLUMN_PREMIUM = "premium"` and `private static let COLUMN_UPDATE_CLEAN = "update"`

Comment: @Vergiliy if the code you've shown does not exhibit any problems, what help do you expect? Post an excerpt that lets others reproduce the error.

Comment: @Gereon Is it possible that a case block will work if there is a partial match of the string? (the line `update` contains the line` date`)?

Comment: @Vergiliy Will not match partially for sure. And I tried it prints `type = update, key = update` correctly. So you have issue somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe there are more options? Just as I understand it - this is impossible, but I have not believed my eyes for two hours already :)

Comment: Make a sample project for this little code snippet and see. If you still facing same issue upload the project on dropbox and share the link.

Comment: @TheTiger I cleared everything and updated the question. Could you see... Any other ideas?

Comment: @TheTiger I found a problem. Updated the question. Thank you for the help!

Comment: A couple of things: First, your update 2 includes non-standard syntax (presumably reliant on other extensions you have in your project). I’d suggest you always keep your examples as simple as possible. E.g. `static func ~= (lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool { return lhs.contains(rhs) }` manifests the problem, too. Second, you should not put answers in your question, but rather [post your own answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I think this a real gem you’ve found, but you’re making it hard for someone to vote for your question, much less your answer.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the information. Delivered the update to a separate response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a problem. In the String class extension, the ~= operator was redefined as follows:

```
extension String {
    static func ~= (lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool {
        return NSRegularExpression(rhs).matches(lhs)
    }
}
```

As it turned out, the `~=` operator is used in a `switch` statement.
To correct the error, I replaced this extension with the following:

```
extension String {
    func matches(pattern: String) -> Bool {
        return NSRegularExpression(pattern).matches(self)
    }
}
```

How I use it:

```
if value.matches(pattern: "#[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]#" {
    // Code
}
```

**It should be very attentive when redefining operators!**